# Problems reading data with python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a waspmote board with event sensors that send data via LoRa to a Gateway, the Gateway Libelium is connected directly via USB PC.

I want to read the Port Serial where is connected the USB, and send data to mysql. I have one Python'sscript but doesn't works, can you help me please?

```
This is my code: #!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
from time import sleep
from serial import *, import serial, import struct, time

os.system("stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 38400")
os.system("stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0")

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout = 1)
while 1:
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 38400, timeout = 1)
data = ser.read(9999)
if len(data) > 0:
    print 'DATA:', data
    ser.close()
    sleep (2)

    celda=data
    celda = data.split("#")
    print celda

    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
          user="root", # your username
          passwd="", # your password
          db="waspmote") # name of the data base

    with con:

            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO datos (Id,Node,Seq,Bateria,temperatura,Luminositat) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(celda[0],celda[1],celda[2],celda[3],celda[4],celda[5]))
            con.commit()
```

And I have this error:

```
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
min = 60; time = 1;
ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
```

`-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SERIAL.PY", line 21, in <module>
    data = ser.read(9999)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 460, in read`
    `raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)`

Can you help me please?

Comment: try your query in the database shell, see if it's working.

Comment: Thakss!! The problem was in the database,now I can receive data.

Comment: But the problem now is store the infromation. I receive the data like this: <=>\0x80\0x03#387242283#node_001#42#BAT:90#TCA:27.42#TCA:33.66. I want to read and store each data separate for #. But with my code only takes the first data.  Can you help me please?

Comment: I solved the problem change this part of code: while True:
   
 data = ser.readline()
 if len(data)!= 0 and data =='\xe24':
  
  print 'DATA', data
  ser.close
  sleep(2)
 elif len(data) > 0:
  celda = data
      celda = data.split("#")
         print 'CELDA', celda
 Thanksss! I hope someone can need this :)